# How to update gitlab deploy token if you already cloned using the old one?

Tags: gitlab

If you clone a Gitlab repository using a deploy token

```
git clone https://$GITLAB_USERNAME:$GITLAB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/group/project.git
```

subsequent git commands will use that token without it being provided again

```
git pull # success
```

But if you revoke the old token and want to update using the same method as before

```
git clone https://$NEW_GITLAB_USERNAME:$NEW_GITLAB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/group/project.git
```

You'll fail

```
git pull # fail 
HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://**OLD_USERNAME**:**OLD_TOKEN**@gitlab.com/group/project.git'
```

Where does Gitlab store that old token? How can I update this?

Answer (score 4):

The authentication is working here simply by the remote url.

```
git remote -v
origin  https://**OLD_USERNAME**:**OLD_TOKEN**@gitlab.com/group/project.git (fetch)
origin  https://**OLD_USERNAME**:**OLD_TOKEN**@gitlab.com/group/project.git (push)
```

So if you have a new token you just need to update the url

```
git remote set-url origin https://$NEW_GITLAB_USERNAME:$NEW_GITLAB_TOKEN@gitlab.com/group/project.git
```